# How to render html string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a server response which contains an html string which is passed to a react component as a prop. Within the html there are codes which need to be replaced with React components.

I've used react-string-replace to get this to work but it doesn't seem to work with HTML as the tags are escaped by React. Does anyone know how this might be fixed?

```
import React from 'react';

import replace from 'react-string-replace';
const reg = /\{(name)\}/g;


const Name = props => {
    return (
        <div>Hello {props.name}</div>
    )
}


class Embed extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const person = this.props.person
        const component = <Name name={person.name} key={person.id} />;
        const output = replace(
            this.props.content,
            reg,
            prop => component
        );

        return (
            <div>{output}</div>
        )
    }
}

const Greeting = props => {
    return <Embed content="<div><h1>Greetings</h1> <strong>{name}</strong></div>" person={{ name: 'John', id: 123 }} />;
};

export default Greeting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
class Embed extends React.Component {

render() {

    const person = this.props.person
    const component = <Name name={person.name} key={person.id} />;
    const output = replace(
        this.props.content,
        reg,
        prop => component
    );

    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: output }}></div>
    )
   }
}
```

I suggest much better way to do it like below -

```js
const reg = /\{(name)\}/g;

const Name = props => {
    return (
        <div>Hello {props.name}</div>
    )
}


class Embed extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const person = this.props.person;
        const component = <Name name={person.name} key={person.id} />;

        return (
            <div><h1>Greetings</h1> <strong>{component}</strong></div>
        );
    }
}

const Greeting = props => {
    return (<Embed person={{ name: 'John', id: 123 }} > 
     
     </Embed>);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting/>,
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Unfortunately that returns the html rendered correctly but the jsx Name component as [object Object]

Comment: May I know why are you passing the string as jsx when you can pass the component itself either via prop or via childrens

Comment: It's a simplified example of what I'm working on but the Embeds component has a content prop which comes from the server. I can't control that it comes as HTML or that it needs to have something from that string replaced.

Comment: `const component = <Name name={person.name} key={person.id} />;` This will not return a string. it is a light weight representation of dom via react elements. So instead of returning Name as element why don't you use  "<div>Hello {props.name}</div>" directly as string and do simple search and replace via regex.

Comment: In the real app I'm working on there are several strings to be replaced with a few different components which are quite a bit more complex.

It would be possible to pass the string as a child of the Embed component rather than a prop though.

Answer (score 0):

Wants to remind you this:

From [Facebook React Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html):

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React's replacement for using innerHTML in
>   the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
>   it's easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
>   (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
>   to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html
>   key, to remind yourself that it's dangerous.

Try this:

```
const Name = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello {props.name}
        </div>
    )
}

class Embed extends React.Component {
    render() {
     let content = this.props.content.replace('{name}', this.props.person.name);
        return (
            <div>
                <Name  person={this.props.person}/>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content}}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Greeting = props => {
    return <Embed content="<div><h1>Greetings</h1> <strong>{name}</strong></div>" person={{ name: 'John', id: 123 }} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Check working example on `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/h81q9nqd/

Comment: Thanks for your response. My example is probably a little too simple. What I really want to achieve is based on the match in the regular expression render a different component. So doing the replacement in the Name component is too late as the decision of what component is to be rendered needs to be made before rendering the Name component.

Comment: you can use reg to prepare the string that you want to render, i dont have idea about `react-string-replace` that why used normal string replace, similarly use reg to prepare the string in ur case, whatever string manipulation i did in Name component we can put that in `Embed` comp also, check updated fiddle :)

Comment: Unfortunately this only replaces parts of the string with a string.  What I'm looking to try to do is replace parts of the string with a component. That's where the need to use react-string-replace came from.

If you see the order of the output in your fiddle it's Hello Greetings John, which should be Greetings Hello John.

Comment: This fiddle doesn't work but it's more like what I'm trying to do:
[https://jsfiddle.net/adamoliver/maatogyg/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/adamoliver/maatogyg/1/)